# Is reading from a struct faster then reading from a class in c++?

Tags: c++

The following two classes are absolutely equivalent in every way except their name:

```
struct s
{
   int x;
};

class c
{
public:
   int x;
};
```

Is there a difference in speed between reading from a struct then a class?

For example,

is

```
int y = s.x
```

Slower then

```
int z = c.x
```

to run? Is one of them less efficient to read from?

Comment: TL; DR: No.  There is no difference, given your example.  Or any other, come to think of it.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from looking at the disassembly.

Comment: `struct` and `class` in C++ is *exactly the same*, except for default access permissions and default inheritance.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if

Comment: imho in it was a mistake to introduce a new keyword `class`, as its main effect is confusion about something that essential. I understand that back then it made sense to make it look "different", but I have seen this misunderstanding even on somewhat experienced programmers which is a little sad